# Shorter jumps with Page Up/Down

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Is there a way/third party app that can make Page Up/Down jump just a few lines? This could be activated by holding down Ctrl or some other key.

I always think Page Up/Down scrolls to much, and holding down the arrow keys takes to long.

I'm using Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing the free, excellent and well documented [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

By pressing Ctrl+Alt and Page Up/Down, the cursor moves 15 lines up/down. Script provided below.

```
^!PgUp::Send {Up 15}
^!PgDn::Send {Down 15}
```

Comment: This saved my soul..Windows should support this feature by default!

Comment: Can confirm, soul saved.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of scrolling I find it best to use a mouse with a scroll wheel, where the scroll amount in lines can be programmed.

This lets me use Page Up/Down or scroll wheel, as appropriate.

Comment: As a programmer I would prefer to use the keyboard. If there is a solution to my problem, I'd probably end up using the mouse less, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: Probably not good for your repetitive strain injury (RSI)

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided works for `AutoHotkey_1.1.33.02`:

- Create a file called scroll_config.ahk
- Copy paste the following in the file

```
PgUp::Send {Up 12}
PgDn::Send {Down 12}
```

- Save and Run the file

Answer (score 0):

***Is there a way/third party app that can make Page Up/Down jump just a few lines?***

> I don't think there is any 3rd party
>   out there for this purpose

***I always think Page Up/Down scrolls to much, and holding down the arrow keys takes to long.***

> I think you need to do a combination
>   of both to get the right page scroll

Comment: Must make one then.

Comment: Try asking about coding a program for this purpose in stack overflow